# How can I get some data frome json file with ArrayDeque?

Tags: android, json, arraydeque, gson

I try to get some data from json file like this.

```
[
  {
    "type": "text",
    "content": "test test test",
    "time": 100
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "content": "abcedfg",
    "time": 100
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "content": "some data",
    "time": 100
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "content": "1234567",
    "time": 100
  }
]
```

And defined a class like this.

```
class TextData {
    String type;
    String content;
    long time;

    TextData(String type, String content, long time) {
        this.type = type;
        this.content = content;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

I tried to ues GSON to parse the json data as `ArrayDeque<TextData>` like this

```
    ArrayDeque<TextData> textDatas = 
            new Gson().fromJson(getJson(fileName), ArrayDeque.class);
```

Method `getJson` will get json file's data whit `String`.

And it's dosen't work. I get this error.

```
failed to deserialize json object "" given the type class java.util.ArrayDeque
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<TextData>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<TextData> arralist = (List<TextData>) gson.fromJson(response, listType);

    for (int i = 0; i < arralist.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("Content", arralist.get(i).getContent());
        Log.e("type", arralist.get(i).getType());
        Log.e("time", arralist.get(i).getTime() + "");
    }
```

> model class

```
public class TextData {
    String type;
    String content;
    long time;

    public TextData(String type, String content, long time) {

        this.type = type;
        this.content = content;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: I got a new question. Now I can parse `String` to `Object` if I define a `String ` in Java class. But when I read data from file, I'll get a `JsonParseExecption`. I confirmed the file is read correctly. But it's just doesn't work.